# pandas load csv file ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, oop

The purpose of this script is to read a csv file and create a pandas data frame then print the first 5 raws using OOP style.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import talib


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
        self.file(self)

    def file(self, file):
        df = pd.read_csv(file, names=self.names,
                         parse_dates={'Release Date': ['Date', 'Time']})
        print(df.head())


x = Data()
x.file(file=r"D:\Projects\Project Forex\EURUSD.csv")
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/project/Technical Analysis.py", line 15, in <module>
    x = Data()

  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/project/Technical Analysis.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.file(self)

  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/project/Technical Analysis.py", line 13, in file
    parse_dates={'Release Date': ['Date', 'Time']})

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 431, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 200, in get_filepath_or_buffer

    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class '__main__.Data'>
```

Comment: it is already in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the last line of `__init__`: `self.file(self)`. When it is called in `__init__`, `self` is a `Data` object, while the `file` method has to be called with a string containing the path of the csv file.

The fix is trivial: remove that line:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

    def file(self, file):
        ...
```

but it is still not consistent: `self.df` is initialized as an empty dataframe, which is fine, but the `file` method does not update it and use instead a local variable `df` (distinct from `self.df` in Python). You should do:

```
def file(self, file):
    self.df = pd.read_csv(file, names=self.names,
                     parse_dates={'Release Date': ['Date', 'Time']})
    print(self.df.head())
```